# How to encode and decode / character with PHP

Tags: php, special-characters, decode, encode

In my dynamically generated website sometimes parts of my URLs contain a / character:

Serena Williams/Venus Williams-Andrea Hlavackova/Lucie Hradecka

And, naturally, the URL returns a 404 error as the / sign is considered a folder so the URL doesn't exist.

What would be the PHP function to encode and later decode the string which contains a / character?

Comment: what rewrite code do you use? never had problem with / myself

Comment: return htmlentities(utf8_encode($s), ENT_HTML401 | ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PHP: urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode and its counterpart [PHP: urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode:

```
urlencode($stringinput)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user htmlentities() whit urlencode()

```
<?php
$query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);
echo '<a href="index.php?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';
?>
```